# FrameLabel and OverTilde

Tags: plotting, labeling

What is the problem with this expression inside ListPrint? [`OverTilde`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OverTilde.html) generates here a mess:

```
FrameLabel->{{"f"<>"("<>ToString[OverTilde["x"]]<>")",None},{"x",None}}
```

Comment: I think you are making this much more complicated than necessary.  I would simply use `FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(~\)]\))"}`.  I entered this as `f(x` Ctrl-7 `~` `)`.  It's readable and easy to format in the notebook, but it becomes a bit ugly when pasting here.

Comment: @Szabolcs and et al., I find it bizarre that, with two answers up as I write this comment, one leapt straight to linear syntax/boxes and the other to fixing up `ToString`.  Both answers are correct and sufficient, but surely a solution involving `Row` is easier to understand and apply to other similar problems.

Comment: @JohnFultz My suggestion wasn't to type the text representation of boxes, as it was pasted here.  I meant typing the equivalent 2D math expression using keyboard shortcuts.  If starting with Ctrl-9 to create an inline cell, then single-character variables will be properly capitalized too.  I find this wysiwyg way of entering the formula quite convenient, and it's what I use myself for plot labels.

Comment: @JohnFultz I guess it depends on whether in responding you answer the specific problem or suggest alternatives that maybe be better. IMO the specific problem is that `ToString` is not by default writing `StandardForm`. I agree though that `Row` ought to be the preferred way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OverTilde["x"]` is a short way of writing `Overscript["x","~"]` so it is not `OverTilde` per se causing the issue here. The problem is that by default `ToString` writes `OutputForm`. So what you need to do is to write the string as `StandardForm`:

`FrameLabel->{{"f"<>"("<>ToString[OverTilde["x"],StandardForm]<>")",None},{"x",None}}`

For example this doesn't work:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"f" <> "(" <> ToString[OverTilde["x"]] <> ")", 
    None}, {"x", None}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "TimesNewRoman"}]
```

[image]

But this works fine:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"f" <> "(" <> 
     ToString[OverTilde["x"], StandardForm] <> ")", None}, {"x", 
    None}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "TimesNewRoman"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is get what JohnFultz suggested in a comment on record.

A simple and easy-to-understand approach using `Row` is demonstrated by

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {x, Row[{"f(", OverTilde["x"], ")"}]},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}]
```

[image: plot.png]

Comment: I guess the point I was making in my comment to john fultz was that the question asked "What is the problem with this expression..." not "what is the best way to ...". Do we answer the actual questions here or do we re-frame questions to ones which we would prefer to answer?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch. Your point is well-taken. I think we should answer the actual question and also reframe and answer them to show better practice.

Comment: I haven't searched but I would guess there must be many answers here that show that `Row` is an optimal approach to this problem. I interpret the question as one which requires an explanation of unexpected `ToString` behaviour ("What is the problem with this expression...").

Answer (score 2):

Frame labels are automatically converted to `TraditionalForm`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, f[\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(~\)]\)]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "TimesNewRoman"}]
```

In the notebook it looks much better:

[image]

I specify `BaseStyle` to enlarge the labels. You can enter `x̃` as `x` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>`~` as Szabolcs write in the comment. More correct to use `HoldForm[x]` and `HoldForm[f[x̃]]` to localize `f` and `x`.

My solution differs from Szabolcs's comment:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(~\)]\))"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "TimesNewRoman"}]
```

[image]

It is because `TraditionalForm` automatically italicizes variables and makes other necessary transformations, e.g. `Sin[x]` → $\sin(x)$, `Hypergeometric2F1[z, b, c, z]` → ${}_2F_1(a,b,c;z)$.

---

Why `"f("<>ToString[OverTilde["x"]]<>")"` works strange?

Answer:

```
ToString[OverTilde["x"]]
```

> ```
> ~
> x
> ```

It is two-line string with `~` over `x`. Therefore

```
"f(" <> ToString[OverTilde["x"]] <> ")"
```

> ```
> f(~
> x)
> ```

`"f("` is prepended to first line and `")"` is appended to the second line. More correct usage:

```
ToString[f[OverTilde["x"]]]
```

> ```
>   ~
> f[x]
> ```